# Ubuntu 18.10 mod rewrite does'nt seem work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.4

I try to use the mod rewrite but it does'nt seem work

If I do http://localhost/test/test.html I have the same thing.
But I will must have http://localhost/test/inconnu.html

Do you have any idea ?

Tk

My process

in sites-availabe in apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

my files

create a directory test

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^inconnu.html$  /test.html [L]
```

my html file test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
toto
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to your rule, when you try http://localhost/test/inconnu.html you should see "toto".

Comment: @VasiliyZverev No it does'nt work

Comment: And you don't have actual inconnu.html file, do you?

Comment: Make sure that .htaccess is enabled at all:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
RewriteRule ^inconnu.html$  /test.html [L]
```

should be either with /test/test.html or test.html.
According to [Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) RewriteBase takes effect only for relative urls (such as "test.html")

```
RewriteRule ^inconnu.html$  test.html [L]
```